# Allow the onclick function to execute only once

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick

I have a gridview in which all the columns are text-boxes. I have implemented, through jquery, an onclick function on the textboxes so that when an user clicks the textbox **a hidden button is clicked which in turn updates an updatepanel and the page reloads**. Also the textbox should be editable. My problem is that the **onclick** function is triggered every time I click the textbox to edit and the page reloads. How to prevent it?

Here is my textbox code:

**Note: This is just code for one textbox. All the textboxes are using the same Onclick funciton**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLoginName" Onclick='<%# "timepass(" + Eval("userid") + ");" %>'
 Text='<%# Eval("LoginName")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And here is the jquery code which triggers a code behind function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function timepass(pass) {
            $("#btnHidden").trigger("click");
        }
    </script>
```

I wanted to go with a hidden column in the gridview whose value changes everytime a text-box is clicked but as there are many text-boxes in the row it becomes increasingly complex so it doesn't look feasible. Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: You should somehow remember that the textbox was clicked

Comment: What is the purpose of the side panel. What is it updating. Also why do you need this update to occur when a text box is clicked.

Comment: @PaulBinder there are 2 more gridviews that populate when the text-box is clicked. On click of the textbox an id is passed based on which the details are populated in the two gridviews

Answer (score 0):

To avoid page refreshes you could simply use an Ajax call.

```
function ajaxCall(passedId){
    $.post('url', { id: ajaxCall}, 
        function(returnedData){
            console.log(returnedData);
            //update grid view with complex javascript
        });
    }
```

Then you can simply use a modified version of Saeb's bind code

```
  $("yourselector").click(function(event) {
    var eventId = event.target.id;
    ajaxCall(eventId);
    $("#" + eventId).unbind( "click", handler );;
});
```

This binds to all your text boxes but unbinds the specific text box. Also, depending on what type of gridview you are using, some third party grids, [like jQuery Grid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/binding-jquery-grid-to-json-data/), allow you to bind JSON objects to them.

**Sample of binding it to a jQuery Grid**

```
$.post('url', { id: "value" },
    function (returnedData) {
        console.log(returnedData);
        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'CompanyName' },
                { name: 'ContactName' },
                { name: 'ContactTitle' },
                { name: 'Address' },
                { name: 'City' },
                { name: 'Country' }
            ],
            localdata: data
        };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(returnedData);
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            source: dataAdapter,
            columns: 
            [
                { text: 'Company Name', datafield: 'CompanyName', width: 250 },
                { text: 'Contact Name', datafield: 'ContactName', width: 150 },
                { text: 'Contact Title', datafield: 'ContactTitle', width: 180 },
                { text: 'City', datafield: 'City', width: 120 },
                { text: 'Postal Code', datafield: 'PostalCode', width: 90 },
                { text: 'Country', datafield: 'Country', width: 100 }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Ajax call is not feasible for me because I was two more gridviews in the update panel below this gridview(not created in the code behind). Using Ajax means using static webmethods and that makes the method to populate gridview way too complex. I will also keep your method as an option but I am looking for something simpler